# Using a straight password for encryption and authentication

Tags: passwords

Assume we have a password like `3buNCh_7kaRmencrEst3`. Now suppose we have two parties who know this password. We a have communication scheme that uses the password to establish session key and to authenticate the handshake used to establish the session key. Assume a password-based key derivation function is used to authenticate the challenge-response protocol used to establish the session key and that that same function is used to generate the session key. Is such a scheme secure?

Comment: I would say that it strongly depends on the precise methods used

Comment: Can you please describe the scheme more precisely? For example how is the PBKDF used to authenticate the handshake?